# notation difference for defining a function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, ag-grid

I am writing a `cellRenderer` component for `ag-grid`.

If I write it like below, it works fine :

```js
function SignalCellRenderer() {}
SignalCellRenderer.prototype.init = function (params) {
    // create the cell
    this.eGui = document.createElement('div');
    this.eGui.innerHTML = '<span class="my-css-class"><button class="btn-simple">Push Me</button><span class="my-value"></span></span>';
};
```

But if I use the below notation, it fails :

```js
let SignalCellRenderer = () => {}
SignalCellRenderer.prototype.init = function (params) {
    // create the cell
    this.eGui = document.createElement('div');
    this.eGui.innerHTML = '<span class="my-css-class"><button class="btn-simple">Push Me</button><span class="my-value"></span></span>';
};
```

with this error message

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'init' of undefined
```

I thought those 2 ways of defining a function were equivalent but clearly not.

Could someone please explain the difference ?

Comment: Arrow functions can't be called with `new`

Comment: thks will ahve a read through your link